# how to change argv string to long integer for quite big number

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

i have question this is code that can change input from terminal , but since the input is from argv, which is string, i need to change string to long integer , when the input is quite big it wont produce correct result. how to fix this?

./k decode E output:4

./k encode 10  output:BB

this produce right result

for example when input is "encode", "276910033818923479812737657823469876718641987649781361463764954098802518764628237467231873628347582973485972834752784935773114658736582736458972634785"
it produce wrong result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ll long long int
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' };
ll decode(string k);
string encode(ll n);
void align(string k);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // start from 1 to ignore script name; argv[0] will be a name of processing file.

        if (strcmp(argv[1], "decode") == 0) {
            string p = argv[2];

            ll total = decode(p);
            cout << total << "\n";
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "encode") == 0) {
            long int yu = strtol(argv[2],NULL,10);
            string str=encode(yu);
            cout<<str<<endl;
        }else if(strcmp(argv[1],"align")==0){
           string k=argv[2];
           align(k);
        }

    return 0;
}


string encode(ll n)
{   int i = 0;
    string str="";
    // array to store binary number
    long binaryNum[1000];
    if(n==0){
        binaryNum[0]=0;
        i++;
    }
    // counter for binary array

    while (n > 0) {

        // storing remainder in binary array
        binaryNum[i] = n % 9;
        n = n / 9;
        ++i;

    }


    long lo;
    // printing code array in reverse order
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        lo = binaryNum[j];
        str+=arr[lo];
        //cout << arr[lo];
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Since the argument passed to main is an `array` of `char*`, maybe change `string p...` to a `char*` and do a full copy using `strcpy`. You might have to calculate the size before doing the copying... If you are using a newer compiler of C++ you might be able to use `auto p = argv[2]` instead of declaring a `string` or a `char*` and performing a call to a copy function. Same thing for `string str...` in the else if and `string k`...

Comment: Note: 276910...785 is a 497-bit number.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite big. Max standard int size is either 32 bit or 64 bits on most machines depending on architecture. It depends on what OS and Compiler you have if there is any support for `Large Int` libraries. Windows is kind of limited, Linux has the GNU... I don't know if a hash table with some combination of `std::bitset` would help or not but that would blow up in memory usage for 497 bits...

Comment: File access is slow, but maybe have the application take the input from the console and write it to a file, then open up that file and read all its contents and store it into a string instead of trying to parse it from argv directly...

Comment: Yeah this is a tough problem...

Comment: @FrancisCugler thankyou so much! if i write the input to a file, that means the input is not char*? so i dont have to change string to char*?

Comment: I was thinking of possible situations that may help you to solve your issue... I'm 100% self taught, so I learn by trial and error and by trying to help others...

Comment: I was trying to think of ways to utilize cache and not have to go to main memory or disc, but in this situation, I'm not sure if you can or not due to the fact that you are getting your input from the I/O. Keyboard I/O is a little faster than disc reads and writes, but both send interrupts to the CPU... so it's hard to tell and depends on the architecture, OS and compiler.

Comment: Unrelated: Take care in the sites you are using as tutorials. They look to be giving you some bad advice. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a non-standard (as in it only exists in a few compilers and could be moved or vanish at any time) and includes pretty much the entire C++ Standard library. Include it and the time it takes to build your program goes way up because of all of the extra files being included (which is funny because if it's used right, it helps speed up compilation). It also makes the other includes in the program pretty much useless.

Comment: Where things get nasty is you now have included just about everything in the `std` namespace. And `using namespace std;` places all of those tens of thousands of identifiers into the global namespace where they will run into names you define. All sorts of strange things can happen as a result.

Comment: `#define ll long long int` is a macro. It does really simple and stupid text substitution. replaces `ll` throughout your code with `long long int`whether it makes sense to do it or not. Prefer `using ll = long long int;`. It's less destructive. In production code, prefer to use `long long int` so people know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> but since the input is from argv, which is string, i need to change
>   string to long integer , when the input is quite big it wont produce
>   correct  result. how to fix this?

There is no fix.

The largest C++ integer (for most desktop systems) is `uint64_t` with 8 bytes (`sizeof(uint64_t)` reports 8).

`UINTMAX_MAX` (defined in `<cstdint>`) is the largest integer that fits in a `uint64_t`, and takes only 20 decimal digits to describe the 64 bits.

You simply can not transform 152 decimal digits, 497 bits, to fit into 64 bits (which can contain values described by up to 20 decimal digits).

---

You may wish to investigate multi-precision libraries.

My favorite is GMP. It provides a `mpz_class` (in the `<gmpxx.h>` header to handle integers.

Using `mpz_class`, I have code that can generate the 45,151 decimal digits that describe 12345! (factorial), with excellent performance.

Comment: "long std::strtol(...)" and "long long std::strtoll(...)" are limited to the size of long on your machine.  Use "sizeof(long)"  and  "sizeof(long long)" to determine the byte size of each.  On my system, a long long int is 8 bytes, and thus identical to  uint64_t.

Comment: Thankyou but if i store input from terminal to file and read it without changing from argv to long, there is no way it can read the 152 digit int?

Comment: There is no 152 digit int in C++ that I know of.  GMP’s mpz_class expands automagically to handle ‘big’  int s,  Yes you can feed it 152 digits.